# Bubble sort while using a while statement

Tags: arrays, sorting, while-loop, bubble-sort

I have to write code to sort some numbers, and although I've decided to use "for" instead of "while", but I'd like to know why it's doing what it is. It's sorting everything but it leaves the 14 where it is, if someone could just explain it that'd be very apprieciated

```
public class SortForMe {

public static void main(String args[]) {
int ListOfNumbers[] = {16, 100, 205, 8, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 15, 10, 14};
int Length = ListOfNumbers.length;
int Sorted = 1;
int T;
int Order = 0;
System.out.println("Given number :");
while(Order < Length) {
  System.out.println("  " + ListOfNumbers[Order]);
  Order++;
                     }
System.out.println("\n");
System.out.println("After Sort:");
while (Sorted < Length) {
  while (Order < Length - Sorted) {
    if (ListOfNumbers[Order] > ListOfNumbers[Order + 1]) {
      int temp = ListOfNumbers[Order];
      ListOfNumbers[Order] = ListOfNumbers[Order + 1];
        ListOfNumbers[Order + 1] = temp;
    }
    Order++;
  }
  Order = 0;
  Sorted++;

}
while(Order < Length) {
  System.out.println(ListOfNumbers[Order]);
  Order++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: You need only one more loop so **int Sorted = 0;**

Answer (score 1):

your implementation looks a little bit complexe. I suggest that you refactor and put the permutation code in a separate method to make it more readable. Also you should check at each iteration weither or not there have been any permutation. If no permutation, then it is done. Otherwise you should iterate again. With some refactoring things get simpler.

Here is an implementation that I did and tested with your input

This `simpleBublleSort' method depends on a swap method and a printArray method (see below)

```
 public  void simpleBubbleSort(int[] datas)
 {
     boolean stillHasDisorder = false;
     do
     {
         stillHasDisorder = false;

         for (int i = 0; i <= datas.length - 2; i++)
         {
             if (new Integer(datas[i]).compareTo(new Integer(datas[i+1])) < 0)
             {
                 swap(datas,i, i + 1);
                 stillHasDisorder = true;


             }

         }

         printArray(datas);

     } while (stillHasDisorder);


 }
```

The swap method is the same as what you are doing to swap two compared elements

```
 public void swap(int[] datas, int position1, int position2)
 {
     int temp = datas[position1];
     datas[position1] = datas[position2];
     datas[position2] = temp;
 }
```

The printArray to make a nice printing of the array after every iteration so we can visually see what's going on

```
 public void swap(int[] datas, int position1, int position2)
 {
     int temp = datas[position1];
     datas[position1] = datas[position2];
     datas[position2] = temp;
 }
```

And here is a demo code using your input datas

```
 public static void doDemo() {
     
     int[] datas = {16, 100, 205, 8, 1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 6, 15, 10, 14};
     (new BubbleSort()).simpleBubbleSort(datas);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     doDemo();
     
 }
```

Here is the result:

> [100 205 16 8 3 2 5 7 6 15 10 14 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 8 3 5 7 6 15 10 14 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 8 5 7 6 15 10 14 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 8 7 6 15 10 14 5 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 8 7 15 10 14 6 5 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 8 15 10 14 7 6 5 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 15 10 14 8 7 6 5 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 15 14 10 8 7 6 5 3 2 1 ]
>
> [205 100 16 15 14 10 8 7 6 5 3 2 1 ]

Of course you can make it ascending by changing the comparison to `>0` instead of `<0`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the variable `Order` in the first loop to show the initial state of the array.

When it's used in the inner loop, it will already be at the end of the array, so nothing is sorted in the first iteration. The `Sorted` variable is increased, leaving the last item unsorted.

Insert an `Order = 0;` between the loop that shows the initial state, and the loops that does the sorting.

Side note: The bubble sort is missing something. It should check if there were any swaps made in the inner loop. If not, the sort is complete, and you can exit the outer loop.